# What is the relationship between Hölder spaces and differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, holder-spaces, fractional-calculus

Let $C^{k,\alpha}$ be a Hölder space where $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$. I have seen various sources informally describe these spaces as functions having at least "$k + \alpha$" derivatives. How does some sense of fractional differentiability follow from the definition of the Hölder norm?

Comment: My guess is that for $\alpha >0$, if you use the characterisation of Holder spaces via the littlewood-paley decomposition and define a fractional derivative via a fourier multiplier it should be possible to read the kind of result you want off the definitions

Comment: @RhysSteele Thank you.